# Username/password dialog from batch script

Tags: windows, vbscript, batch-file, passwords

I need to prompt for a username and password from a batch script subroutine and I have the following requirements:

1. Must be user-friendly (i.e. not on the command line, but from a
   dialog box).
2. Must mask the password.
3. Must not require customized settings or installation before I run the batch script (no AutoIT or odd IE settings).
4. Must be compatible with Windows XP, 2008, and 7 (though if variations on a theme are appropriate I can check the specific OS).

I'm assuming that I may need to use VBscript, which I can easily create from within the batch script and then delete afterward.  I did find [this link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/02/04/how-can-i-mask-passwords-using-an-inputbox.aspx), with two different VBScript options, but the first one violates requirement 1 (console based), and the second violates requirement 3 (default IE settings aren't allowing dynamic content these days).  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HTML Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28VS.85%29.aspx) might work for you.  You could create a simple page with an `<input type="password" />` control.  I can't think of a good way to get the password from the HTA back to the batch file, though, other than writing the password to a temporary file, or maybe a registry key.

Comment: That's basically what the 2nd method in the link I attached was doing.  It sort-of works, but it requires a <script> tag, which modern default settings for IE flag as dangerous and therefore it requires custom IE settings to not show big warning messages.  Is there a better way that doesn't produce the warning?

Comment: The link suggests making a regular HTML file and using IE automation to open it from a VBScript file.  An HTML Application is different.  It is a standalone file with a `.HTA` file extension that is executed outside of the normal IE security sandbox.  You shouldn't get any security warnings.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize the difference.  You are right, an HTA does bypass the security issues of an html page.  I'll post my complete solution when I have it, but I'll give you credit for the answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Is using Powershell out of the question?

You can use [Get-Credential](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315327.aspx) to [prompt for authentication.](http://www.myitforum.com/articles/1/view.asp?id=12150)

```
$Credentials = Get-Credential Domain\UserName
```

Edit:

Another option if distributing this application is to just put the prompt for a username and password in the installer.  You could do this in an MSI, but it is probably a lot more overhead than you'd want.  You could instead use [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) and prompt for the info in the installer wizard. NSIS is self-contained and would run on all the OS's you specified.

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks my 3rd requirement since I'd have to have powershell installed ahead of time (as far as I can tell).

Comment: It was integrated in Win 7.  I assume you're installing on a different OS.

Comment: Good to know, but I did already add a clarifying 4th requirement for OS compatibility.  Unfortunately, I need compatibility with XP, 2008 AND Windows 7.

Comment: What service pack has your Windows XP installation got? If I'm not mistaken, Windows XP SP3 comes with integrated PS 1.0.

Answer (score 1):

I would write a native C++ or Delphi application that consists of a single dialog with a password input field.

Compiling this to a single executable and returning the entered value to the calling process, the batch script could ship with the executable in the same folder and use it to query for the password.

If .NET is an option, write a WindowsForms application instead of native C++ (for speed of development)

Comment: That's a possibility, though one I was hoping to avoid.  If I have to go this route, I'll probably just write a simple java app since I'm distributing this with a larger Java application.